# Page Sizes (SSD)

Tags: partitioning, ssd, storage

New storage devices like hard disks are being made using the "new" IDMEA [advanced format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_format) of physical 4KB sectors, but what is the largest page size SSD comes in?

Looking [around](http://www.oo-software.com/en/docs/whitepaper/whitepaper_ssd.pdf) I could only find 4KB as the largest (512KB *logically). (see below)

> SSD layout In contrast to the hard disk, a SSD consists of
>   semiconductor memory building blocks, it contains no mechanical parts.
>   The smallest unit of an SSD is a page, which is composed of several
>   memory cells, and is usually 4 KB in size. Several pages on the SSD
>   are summarized to a block. A block is the smallest unit of access on a
>   SSD. Currently, 128 pages are mostly combined into one block;
>   therefore, a block contains 512 KB.

Is there any manufacture making larger physical page sizes or block sizes for SSDs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, [there are SSDs with 8K or even 16K pages](http://web.archive.org/web/20150920050514/http://www.hardocp.com/article/2013/05/28/crucial_m500_480gb_ssd_review/2#.Vf4-kVDLfiw).

[Coding for SSDs – Pages, Blocks, and the Flash Translation Layer - Code Capsule](http://codecapsule.com/2014/02/12/coding-for-ssds-part-3-pages-blocks-and-the-flash-translation-layer/) says though that it isn't practical to ram it up just for the heck of it:

- as page size grows, so does write amplification (the term's also explained on the link)
- NAND memory is rather slow by itself; striping and streamlining is needed to compensate. Larger read granularity makes this harder.

Thus, they apparently balance it to keep the number of [pages/blocks/etc](http://www.flashmemorysummit.com/English/Collaterals/Proceedings/2012/20120821_TB11_Sykes.pdf) manageable for very large SSDs (the 1st linked article talks about 480GB and 960GB(!) ones).

Answer (score 5):

One can find the papers published by the manufacturers according to you SSD's NAND type, for examples:

- **Samsung QLC** (16KB):

  - Kim, Doo-Hyun, et al. "13.1 A 1Tb 4b/cell NAND Flash Memory with t PROG= 2ms, tR= 110µs and 1.2 Gb/s High-Speed IO Rate." 2020 IEEE International Solid-State Circuits Conference-(ISSCC). IEEE, 2020.
- **Samsung TLC** (16KB):

  - Kim, Chulbum, et al. "A 512-gb 3-b/cell 64-stacked wl 3-d-nand flash memory." IEEE Journal of Solid-State Circuits 53.1 (2017): 124-133.
- **Intel QLC** (16KB):

  - Khakifirooz, Ali, et al. "30.2 A 1Tb 4b/Cell 144-Tier Floating-Gate 3D-NAND Flash Memory with 40MB/s Program Throughput and 13.8 Gb/mm 2 Bit Density." 2021 IEEE International Solid-State Circuits Conference (ISSCC). Vol. 64. IEEE, 2021.

Comment: Do you have links? If so, please [edit] your answer and add them.

Comment: Unfortunately, these papers are not placed in public, I use the account from my school library, it seems that the direct link is not accessable. May be [sci-hub](https://sci-hub.ren/) may have some of them.